# Uploading files from a Python client to a Django Server

Tags: python, django, file, post, upload

I'm trying to upload some files from a Python client to a Django web app.

I'm able to do it by using a form, but I don't know how to do it using a stand alone Python app. Can you give me some suggestions?

I'm modeling the files in a Django model like this:

```
class Media(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False,null=False)
    mediafile = models.FileField(upload_to=media_file_name, blank=False,null=False)
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually working right now using Python's requests module

Ill put the code for all interested...

Django server...

urls.py

```
...
url(r'^list/$', 'dataports.views.list', name='list'),
...
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "upload file----------------------------------------------"
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print "otra vez.. es valido"
            print request.FILES

            newdoc = Jobpart(
                                partfile = request.FILES['docfile']
            )
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dataports.views.list'))
    else:
        #print "nooooupload file----------------------------------------------"
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form


    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'data_templates/list.html',
        {'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

list.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Minimal Django File Upload Example</title>   
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
        <form action="{% url "list" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p>
                {{ form.docfile }}
            </p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Now in the client.

client.py

```
import requests
url = "http://localhost:8000/list/"
response = requests.post(url,files={'docfile': open('test.txt','rb')})
```

Now you are able to add some security and stuff.. But it is actually a very simple example..

Thank you all!!!!

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is to send a `POST` request to the Django app sending a file within it.

You can use python's standard library [`httplib` module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/httplib.html?highlight=post) or the 3rd party [`requests` module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file).That last link posted shows how to *post a multipart encoded file* which is probably what you need.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads):

```
with open('file') as f:
    requests.post('http://some.url/upload', data=f)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
file = request.FILES['file']

load_file = FileSystemStorage()

filename = load_file.save(file.name, file)  // saving in local directory and getting filename

data = {'name': name, 'address': address, 'age':age }

fr_data = None
with open(filepath ,'rb') as fr:
    fr_data += fr.read()

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'

response = requests.post(url=url, data=data, files= {
                          'filefiledname': fr_data
                          }
                         )
```

Comment: As you're answering a post that's over 5 years old, it would be better if you could add some context to your answer and what it adds compared to the other answers, rather than just posting code.